# dart - pulling static methods from generic extensions

Tags: dart

Here's the singleton pattern code I was implementing in dart:

```
void main() {
  var func = new Functioner();
  print("The output is: ${func.divide()(8) }");
}

class Functioner{
Function divide(){
  Function letUsDivide = (int x)=>x~/4;
  return letUsDivide;
  }
  
  static Functioner _mThis = null;
  
  Functioner(){
    _mThis = this;
  }
  
  static Functioner getInstance(){
    if(_mThis == null)
      _mThis = new Functioner();
    return _mThis;
  }
  
  
  int divideInts(int a, int b){
    return (a/b).toInt();
  }
  
  
  
}

class MathGen<T extends Functioner>{
  MathGen();
  
  int divide(){
    Functioner mVal = T;
    double a = 3.5;
    
        
    return T.getInstance().divideInts(3,54); #error
  }
  
}
```

Since dart's generics allowed making them a subclass of a particular type, I thought static fields and methods would be allowed, but I was wrong. As marked inside the `MathGen` class with `error` line says:  `the method getInstance() isn't defined for the type 'Type'` , but

1. shouldn't this syntax `T extends Functioner` mean that `T` is atleast a
   `Functioner` type?
2. then why is `getInstance()` not available
3. and how do I cast `T` to a `Functioner`? (From what I have found
   dart seems to not have a explicit casting mechanism?)

Comment: yes, that answers 50% of it and 50% is below. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
   Functioner getInstance(){
    if(_mThis == null)
      _mThis = new Functioner();
    return _mThis;
  }
```

make `getInstance()` an instance method, then call it like this:

```
class MathGen<T extends Functioner>{
  MathGen();
  
  T widget;
  
  int divide(){
    double a = 3.5;
    
        
    return widget.getInstance().divideInts(3,54);
  }
  
}
```